# Read and Parse JSON data from POST request in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm doing a POST request via JQuery's Ajax, with the type of data defined as `json`, containing the values to be posted to server, something like `Username: "Ali"`.

What I need to do in a Handler, is to read the values, deserialize them to an object named `User`.

```
String data = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(data);
```

While debugging, the value of `data` is the following:

`Username=Ali&Age=2....`

Now I'm sure this isn't `JSON`, so the next line would certainly produce an error:

```
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: U. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

What is the proper way to read `JSON` data from POST request?

**Client Side**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:38504/DeviceService.ashx",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      Username: 'Ali',
      Age: 2,
      Email: 'test'
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
  });
```

Comment: post the string returning from that POST request.

Comment: @AshokDamani isn't it the value of `data`?

Comment: Well this is a full String, `Username=Ali&Age=2&Email=test`, same things repeating...

Comment: looks like your string is encoded like an url. Maybe if you pass it to an url decoder it might work (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Luke I added the jQuery part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your object to json string:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:38504/DeviceService.ashx",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      Username: 'Ali',
      Age: 2,
      Email: 'test'
    }),
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why your datastring is encoded like an url (as it seems).

But this might solve the problem (altough i am not sure)

```
String data = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
String fixedData = HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(data);
User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(fixedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This In c# file... Will give you result you require...

```
string username=Request.Form["Username"].ToString();
```

Similarly For others...
I hope this will help you

Another Answer Or you can send data like this

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '../Ajax/Ajax_MasterManagement_Girdle.aspx',
                    data: "Age=5&id=2"
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```

ANd get the answer like this in c#

```
string Age=Request.Form["Age"].ToString();
```